# Android Scroll layout up when keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-softkeyboard, android-nestedscrollview

My UI looks like the one below.

[image]

All these are inside a nestedScroll which is inside a constraintLayout. The buttons are aligned to the bottom. I want to scroll the whole view up till the buttons are visible. I tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"`but this brings only the buttons up and it overlaps with TextView 2 and 3. Is there a way to scroll the whole view up so that textView 2, textView 3 and buttons are visible and are not overlapping. Its fine if the textView 1 at the top is hidden

Comment: Have you tried `adjustPan`?

Comment: @BilalNaeem Yes. Adding this din't even bring up the buttons